# Media query based on condition

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I understand that media queries are conditional in-and-of themselves; however is there a 'right', (non-hackish) solution to apply `media query #1` if element 'x' exists (whether it is `display:none;`) on the page, and if not, apply `media query #2`?

The default media query would be something similar to this..

```
@media (max-width: 780px) {
  .right-col {
    float:left;
    width:98%;
  }
  .left-col {
    float:left;
    width:98%;
  }

}
```

while the other media query would merely change the breakpoint..

```
@media (max-width: 600px) { ...
```

Example [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZPBYD4Ox6OstPCD5fo8E?p=preview)

I am looking to determine if the `.sidebar` is visible (whether it is `display:none;`). Depending on it's visibility I want to use a different media query so that my columns collapse at a different breakpoint than previously.

Comment: If the visibility of the sidebar is toggled based on media query, you can use media query for changing how the columns collapse. If this is not the case, though, you might want to clarify what do you mean by visibility: within the viewport (entirely or partly), zero opacity, hidden visibility or display none?

Comment: Sorry, edited to clarify determined based on css display property.

Comment: You'd probably have to add different classes using javascript, and then just style each new class differently.

Comment: @Megan great idea, I hadn't thought that out.